Check if a contract function is Pure or View in solidity
Is there any way to check if a contract is view or pure from solidity
Lets say I have a contract:
contract ContractToCheck {
    uint private value;

    function getValue() external view returns (uint) {
        return value;
    }

    function setValue(uint _value) external {
        value = _value;
    }

    function compute(uint _a, uint _b) external pure returns (uint) {
        return _a + _b;
    }
}

From a seperate contract I would like to check if the contract is view or pure from another contract,  not sure if that possible currently, but maybe there's some way to check in at the assembly level?
Note: I've already checked Chat GPT and it gives me a bad answer so please no AI for answers

You can check whether a function is either view / pure or not, by doing a staticcall to the function from another contract.
Here's the minimal example for the same:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract ContractToCheck {
    uint256 private value;

    function getValue() external view returns (uint256) {
        return value;
    }

    function setValue(uint256 _value) external {
        value = _value;
    }

    function compute(uint256 _a, uint256 _b) external pure returns (uint256) {
        return _a + _b;
    }
}

contract ContractChecker {
    error ContractChecker__InvalidNumberOfArgs();

    function isViewOrPureFunction(
        address _contract,
        string memory _signature,
        uint256[] memory _args
    ) external view returns (bool success) {
        if (_args.length == 0) {
            (success, ) = _contract.staticcall(
                abi.encodeWithSignature(_signature)
            );
        } else if (_args.length == 1) {
            (success, ) = _contract.staticcall(
                abi.encodeWithSignature(_signature, _args[0])
            );
        } else if (_args.length == 2) {
            (success, ) = _contract.staticcall(
                abi.encodeWithSignature(_signature, _args[0], _args[1])
            );
        } else {
            revert ContractChecker__InvalidNumberOfArgs();
        }

        return success;
    }
}

OUTPUT

Checking getValue:


Checking setValue(uint256):


Checking compute(uint256,uint256):



NOTE: This approach can't be used to distinguish between view and pure functions, as the staticcall can be made to both view as well as pure functions.

The issue is that this assume i know a valid sequence of parameters to call the function with, if there was a validation that required arg 1 to be greater than 5 for instance I would not be aware of what parameters to supply at runtime.

I will mark this as correct since you provided a working example, and although it wont work for what i need its a good answer in general
